# dependent dropdown from database for list of addrows

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

I have done this add row and insert concept from this link:-Dynamically Add / Remove input fields in Laravel 5.8 using Ajax jQuery:-https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KqDpESFmLrg .This is working fully exact but i need to get the first name and last name from database and also last name should be dependent on first name .Please help i am unable to find the solution from few days i am struck here.

```
<html>
 <head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Laravel 5.8 - DataTables Server Side Processing using Ajax</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="container">    
     <br />
     <h3 align="center">Dynamically Add / Remove input fields in Laravel 5.8 using Ajax jQuery</h3>
     <br />
   <div class="table-responsive">
                <form method="post" id="dynamic_form">
                 <span id="result"></span>
                 <table class="table table-bordered table-striped" id="user_table">
               <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th width="35%">First Name</th>
                    <th width="35%">Last Name</th>
                    <th width="30%">Action</th>
                </tr>
               </thead>
               <tbody>

               </tbody>
               <tfoot>
                <tr>
                                <td colspan="2" align="right">&nbsp;</td>
                                <td>
                  @csrf
                  <input type="submit" name="save" id="save" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save" />
                 </td>
                </tr>
               </tfoot>
           </table>
                </form>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

 var count = 1;

 dynamic_field(count);

 function dynamic_field(number)
 {
  html = '<tr>';
        html += '<td><input type="text" name="first_name[]" class="form-control" /></td>';
        html += '<td><input type="text" name="last_name[]" class="form-control" /></td>';
        if(number > 1)
        {
            html += '<td><button type="button" name="remove" id="" class="btn btn-danger remove">Remove</button></td></tr>';
            $('tbody').append(html);
        }
        else
        {   
            html += '<td><button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success">Add</button></td></tr>';
            $('tbody').html(html);
        }
 }

 $(document).on('click', '#add', function(){
  count++;
  dynamic_field(count);
 });

 $(document).on('click', '.remove', function(){
  count--;
  $(this).closest("tr").remove();
 });

 $('#dynamic_form').on('submit', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url:'{{ route("dynamic-field.insert") }}',
            method:'post',
            data:$(this).serialize(),
            dataType:'json',
            beforeSend:function(){
                $('#save').attr('disabled','disabled');
            },
            success:function(data)
            {
                if(data.error)
                {
                    var error_html = '';
                    for(var count = 0; count < data.error.length; count++)
                    {
                        error_html += '<p>'+data.error[count]+'</p>';
                    }
                    $('#result').html('<div class="alert alert-danger">'+error_html+'</div>');
                }
                else
                {
                    dynamic_field(1);
                    $('#result').html('<div class="alert alert-success">'+data.success+'</div>');
                }
                $('#save').attr('disabled', false);
            }
        })
 });

});
</script>
```

this is bladephp

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\DynamicField;
use Validator;

class DynamicFieldController extends Controller
{
    function index()
    {
     return view('dynamic_field');
    }

    function insert(Request $request)
    {
     if($request->ajax())
     {
      $rules = array(
       'first_name.*'  => 'required',
       'last_name.*'  => 'required'
      );
      $error = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);
      if($error->fails())
      {
       return response()->json([
        'error'  => $error->errors()->all()
       ]);
      }

      $first_name = $request->first_name;
      $last_name = $request->last_name;
      for($count = 0; $count < count($first_name); $count++)
      {
       $data = array(
        'first_name' => $first_name[$count],
        'last_name'  => $last_name[$count]
       );
       $insert_data[] = $data; 
      }

      DynamicField::insert($insert_data);
      return response()->json([
       'success'  => 'Data Added successfully.'
      ]);
     }
    }
}
```

This is controller

Comment: Your reference link does not exists also you need to post what you have done and exactly what problem you are facing.

Comment: sorry i am going to edit

Comment: this is the example i have done with this i need dependent dropdowns in each row comming from database. i have link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1ebJyK6tocI I want this also combined with the above example.

Comment: Can you write your code here, instead of 26 min video

Comment: ok  i will post the code

Comment: So your data insertion is proper but you want to retrive data

Comment: ya it is inserting !! but i need first name and last name comming from database as i keep them select drop downs . from another table i need to retrive first name and last name like if i select first name it should give its list of last names.just like country  and states.

Comment: I hope you understood